# Why does this group by statement return no rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

My readings table schema looks like this:

```
id | date | item_id | module_id | reading
```

My basic query is working and returns always **one row** (with a value if there are readings between the specified dates, and with null if there aren't).

```
select SUM(`reading`) as `reading` from `readings` 
where `item_id`=1 
and `date` between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-20';
```

But now I want to add a group by statement like this:

```
select SUM(`reading`) as `reading` from `readings` 
where `item_id`=1 
and `date` between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-20'
group by `module_id`;
```

It now returns one row only when there are readings between the specified dates. If there are no readings between the specified dates, it returns **zero rows**.

My question is why does adding this group by statement return no rows? How do I make it behave consistently?

Comment: How would you want it to behave with `GROUP BY module_id`? How many rows should be returned?

Comment: it means there is only one module_id value in your table

Comment: In order to make meaningful use of GROUP BY you should add `module_id` to your SELECT clause before the SUM(`reading`) - this would then give you the sum of reading per module_id between the given dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have a `group by` statement, the SQL definition is to create one group for the results.  This is true even when no rows match.

When you have a `group by` statement, then each group is created.  If there are no rows, then no groups are created.

In some ways, this behavior is inconsistent, but it is how SQL works.  If you want to get more rows, you can re-write the query using conditional aggregation:

```
select module_id,
       SUM(case when `item_id`= 1 and `date` between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-20' then `reading`
           end) as `reading`
from `readings` 
group by `module_id`;
```

This will return a row for each `module_id`.  If no rows match the conditions, then the value of `reading` will be `NULL`.  You can make it `0` instead by adding `else 0` to the `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

its working for me

```
select SUM(m.`reading`) as `reading` from `readings` as m,`readings` as n
where m.item_id=1 
and m.`date` between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-20'
group by n.`module_id`;
```